# Windows 11 iso file fails to mount

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11, mount, iso-image

I downloaded the [latest windows 11 ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11). I verified that:

- the SHA256 checksum matches
- the ISO is unblocked
- The ISO is not sparse.

Trying to mount through Windows Explorer results in the following error:

[image: Sorry, there was a problem mounting the file.]

Trying to mount with `Powershell` using the following command:

```
Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "C:\Downloads\Win11_23H2_English_x64v2.iso"  -StorageType ISO -PassThru | Get-Volume
```

Results in the following error:

```
Mount-DiskImage : The semaphore timeout period has expired.
At line:1 char:1
+ Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath "C:\Downloads\Win11_23H2_Engli ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_DiskImage ...torageType = 1):ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_DiskImage) [Mou
   nt-DiskImage], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070079,Mount-DiskImage
```

Comment: The error you received likely has nothing to do with the ISO itself.  There are far too many causes for `The semaphore timeout period has expired.`

Comment: As a test, I just downloaded the ISO to a rather slow (Pentium N3700) laptop running Win 10 and the ISO opened in both Explorer (which it mounted as an ersatz DVD) and in 7-Zip. All folders could be browsed, the larger WIM was opened in7-Zip, and some MSC utilities run from there. It appears there are issues with your OS. Try SFC and DISM to repair, or reinstall Windows. Alternatively, just use 7-Zip to explore the ISO.